# forEach returning undefined when comparing option values and returning parent id

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting, htmlcollection

So I want to grab all the `<select>` elements and grab the ID of a "country" drop down.

I have the following, which pushes the `<selects>` into a HTMLcollection then compares the first option, which is usually 'Afghanistan'. If true is returns the value of the parentName.id

Thats the theory, but I keep getting undefined. Any insight would be appreciated?

```
const selectsAvailable = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
            countryList = Object.keys(selectsAvailable).forEach((collectedSelect, i) => {
    selectsAvailable[collectedSelect].options[0].value === 'Afghanistan' && selectsAvailable[collectedSelect].options[0].parentNode.id;
});

console.log("countryList>>>>>>", countryList);
```

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything take a look at `filter` or `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax seems a little off. Using `.map()` will return something if it meets the condition, but `.map()` doesn't work on a `nodelist` so you need to convert it to an `array`.

> `.filter()` is perfect for something like this, but it returns the HTML element and not the ID, so we'll stick with `.map()`.

Also, you're looping through the `<select>` elements, so you don't need to traverse up to the parent element. Finally, to avoid empty array items for non-matching `<select>` elements—this is where `.filter()` would've been great—I'm pushing the IDs to the array instead of declaring the function in the variable:

```js
const selectsAvailable = [...document.getElementsByTagName("select")];
let countryList = [];
selectsAvailable.map(item => {
    return item.options[0].value === 'Afghanistan' ? countryList.push(item.id) : ''
});

console.log("countryList>>>>>>", countryList);
```

```html
<select id="countries">
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
</select>

<select id="somethingElse">
  <option value="Something">Something</option>
  <option value="Something">Something</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Sharper I just realised that I'm not even returning anything, because I'm using a condition to push something to an array. `.forEach()` would actually work in this case I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this either using foreach loop or map
Mistake is there is no return inside the loop

Hope this help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <select id="1">
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
    </select>
    <select id="2">
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
        <option value="SriLanka">Sri Lanka</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

        var countryList = [];

        const selectsAvailable = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        Object.keys(selectsAvailable).forEach((collectedSelect, i) => {
            selectsAvailable[collectedSelect].options[0].value === 'Afghanistan' ?
                countryList.push(selectsAvailable[collectedSelect].options[0].parentNode.id) : ''
        });

        console.log("countryList>>>>>>", countryList);
    });

</script>
```